# Using INDIRECT and INDEX(MATCH) in SUMIF

Tags: excel

In the attached worksheet, I want to know how to replace the `SUMIF` formula in the top part of the "Aggregate" worksheet and use a dynamic `INDIRECT(INDEX(MATCH))` formula to achieve the same result. That way if more investors are added the formula can be dragged across the table without having to update the row in the original `SUMIF` formula.

I think `INDIRECT` is the right way to do this. But I can't figure out how to integrate `INDEX(MATCH)` properly.

[image]

[image]

Every formula I tried failed. I have problems with looking up both income type and using `MATCH` to find the row the investor sits on in "TestFund" worksheet.

Comment: You haven't provided your `SUMIF` formula.

Comment: If you're truly using Excel, there's no need to use indirect and you should try to avoid it as it's a volatile function (requires unneeded calculations),